# Can I remove a barcode sticker from the back cover of my passport after a biometrics appointment?

Tags: biometric-passports

I went and gave my Biometrics on 31 may 2019 for us visa in Hyderabad, when I went there they stuck a barcode behind the passport. While I was applying for another visa they had removed it. My interview date is on 19 July 2019 will it cause any problem without the barcode.

Comment: By "behind the passport", do you mean on the back cover?

Comment: Yes on the back cover

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that matters on the outside of a passport is the name of the country that issued it. Other than that, no sticker, no note, no nothing on the cover matters a dime to anybody.

There is no problem whatsoever in removing it from the cover after receiving your passport back.

It is nothing more than a tracking number that helps them keep track of your passport throughout the application/courier process.

It has no bearing on the outcome of your interview and the validity of your passport.

Imagine never being allowed to remove similar barcodes from your luggage after your flights, that would be a mess.  Remove them as you please after they are no longer needed.

> Help me ,because I have a interview today

You are panicking for no reason at all. A barcode sticker that one Visa center put has no bearing on another visa application for a different country, whether that bar code is there or not. That should the be the least of your worries on an interview day.